# Is there an invariant for mapping $(p,q) \mapsto (\frac{p}{1-(1-p)q}, \frac{qp}{1-(1-p)q})$?

Tags: arithmetic

Suppose starting with $0<p,q<1$, mapping $f(p,q)$ that maps $(p,q)$ to $f(p,q) = \left(\frac{p}{1-(1-p)q}, \frac{qp}{1-(1-p)q}\right)$.

Is there an invariant for this mapping $f$, such as $g$, so that
$g(p,q)  = g(f(p,q))$?

Comment: It looks like a logical operator that would check that p and q remain between 0 and 1 is an invariant of the map, sign(p) for example, or sign(1-p).  I take it you are looking for something less trivial?

Comment: yes, i'm looking for something less trivial.

Comment: OK, I found it, replace $q$ with $1-q$, the symmetry will show.

Comment: It is perfectly OK to post an answer to your own question.

Comment: @dxiv I replied in another post: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1987471/26632

Comment: Thanks, though that iteration looks a bit different (there is no $p$ factor in the numerator of the second coordinate of the transform, for one thing). Also, it's not clear to me which is the invariant $g(p,q)$ in that case, either.